# Is there a better way to detect that my Perl script was called from "firstboot"?

Tags: linux, perl, redhat

I have a Perl script that needs to act in a particular way if it was invoked by the firstboot script or invoked by a process that firstboot spawned.  I have this routine `handleFirstBoot` and it seems to work ok, but there is probably better way to write this routine.  So please take a look ...

```
sub handleFirstBoot {
    my $child_id = shift || $$;
    my $parent_id;
    foreach (`ps -ef`) {
        my ($uid,$pid,$ppid) = split;
        next unless ($pid eq $child_id);
        $parent_id = $ppid;
        last;
    }    
    if ( $parent_id == 0 ) {
        debug "firstboot is NOT an ancestor.\n";
        return;
    }    
    my $psout = `ps -p $parent_id | tail -1 |sed -e's/^ //g'| sed -e's/  */ /g'|cut -d' ' -f4`;
    if ( $psout =~ /firstboot/ ) {
        debug "firstboot IS an ancestor. Set post option.\n";
        $opt{'post'} = 1; 
        return;
    } else {
        # recursive case
        handleFirstBoot($parent_id);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why exactly does the script need to care?

Comment: Check whether `getpgrp()` returns 0 in the firstboot case and nonzero otherwise; I suspect it does, and you can replace all of your code with that.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. There may be solutions that don't involve checking the parent process. What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments so far! This Perl script is normally run from cron.  It is collects a bunch of info about the server and sends it via http to a central server.  Overtime the number of host that run the script got a point where too many hosts were try to report at once.  So someone put in a bit of code that make the script sleep from 0 to 16 hrs. (not my idea) Then someone from the OS team figures they need to run this script from the systems firstboot script so now the firstboot script hangs for 0 to 16 hours.  Anyways a lot of bad decisions have been made (see next comment)

Comment: A lot of bad decisions have been made along the way and I been told to shut up and fix they way I have been told to fix it :) Personally I'd replace the whole script with a `curl ... facter` and I wouldn't do the randomized delay in the script but inside the cron file, but hey it pays the bills ;)

Comment: So the script needs to NOT sleep for a 0 to 16 hours if firstboot called it.

Comment: Why not just use `@reboot` in your crontab instead of using firstboot? (assuming `@reboot` is supported in your version of cron)

Comment: ^-- Ah, re-reading your comment, I guess "I been told to shut up and fix they way I have been told to fix it" is why.

Comment: yep ;)  and there is arguments for doing things the way we do.  Mostly because it's a large organization and the only thing my group has control over is this script.  We cannot get everyone to set up their cron jobs the right way and we cannot prevent other groups from invoking our script.

Comment: I think my first tactic would be to look at the difference between the cron and first boot environments. Only sleep if you detect the cron environment.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but `ps -p $PID -o ppid=` would be more efficient than your first _ps_ loop.  (`ps -q $PID -o ...` if your _ps_ supports it.)  On my system, your _tail/sed/cut_ line fails on low-numbered PIDs, which are space padded.  `ps -p $PID -o comm=` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I offer an alternative approach - from the comments, the problem you are trying to solve is a startup script stalling because it's waiting for this one to return.

So can I suggest that `fork()` is probably your friend here?

```
 my $pid = fork(); 
 if ( $pid ) { 
     exit; 
 }
 sleep $delay_time; 
 do_stuff();
```

What will happen is - your script will be called, and the caller will return immediately, but a parallel instance will spawn and delay the random delay interval - and for bonus points, this will work the same in `cron` too.

But as you seem to note in the comments - the 'good' solution is not to do it that way at all - I would suggest that looking at say, `anacron` which is available on most Linux systems would be exactly the tool for this particular job.